# multiplying arrays with array_multiply() is returning an empty array

Tags: php, arrays, multiplication

I am trying to multiply two arrays together (price and user entered quantity.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

unset($_POST['submit']);
$r=array(); 
$userqty=array();
$userqty=$_POST;    

    function array_multiply($userqty, $fullbox) {

    if (!is_array($userqty) || !is_array($fullbox)) {
        exit('Needs to be an array.');
    }

    $c1 = count($userqty);
    $c2 = count($fullbox);

    if ($c1 != $c2) {
        exit('$setOne and $setTwo must be the same length.');
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $c1; $i++) {
        $r[$i] = $userqty[$i] * $fullbox[$i];
    }

    return $r;

}
var_dump($fullbox);
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
var_dump($userqty);
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
var_dump($r);
}
```

When I do the array dump at the end I see my values are correct in my array except the value of my resulting array is **array(0) { }**  When it should have the same number or entries as my original two.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Silly question - you don't seem to be calling your function at all....

Comment: Plus variable scoping rules - you're initializing your `$r` array OUTSIDE of the function - it will not be visible inside your function unless you make it `global`, plus what andrewsi said - you're not calling your function.

Comment: The question is not silly - even if this is the cause of the problem, we are all fallible. @Djacksway - any reason you're declaring `userqty` as an empty array then immediately overwriting it on the next line?

Comment: @Utkanos I figured I would have to declare the variable an array so I could set it equal to the $_post array I obtained from my form.

Comment: Nah - you don't need to do any preparatory work on variables in PHP. One assignment overrides another. Removing the original `array()` assignment will have no change of effect.

Comment: We are all fallible, but StackOverflow isn't supposed to be a super-simple error-correction mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of problems here!

- `$r` is a local variable. Either make it global (don't), or just use the return value.
- You don't actually call the function.
- You don't declare `$r`, even if it is done implicitly for you.

The quick fix:

```
var_dump(array_multiply($userqty, $fullbox));
```

A thorough rewrite:

```
function array_multiply($a, $b) {
    $len = count($a);

    if($len !== count($b)) {
        throw new LengthException('The two arguments to array_multiply should have the same length.');
    }

    $result = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $result[] = $a[$i] * $b[$i];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And don't just pass in `$_POST`, either. That'll be trouble.

Comment: `$fullbox` also doesn't seem to be initialised.